# How to change the background of the child window from an MDI Visual C++ 2008 application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have an MDI Visual C++ 2008 application based on MFC. I am trying to find a way to use an image as background for the child window (child frame). I have been looking on various sites but I can't seem to find a solution. Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: Just paint the image in [OnEraseBkgnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always the same way when you want to change the background of a window.

Handle the WM_ERASEBKGND (OnEraseBkGnd). Draw the bitmap on the given DC and return TRUE
Either use StretchBlt or use it as a brush.

```
BOOL CMyClientWnd::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{  
   CBrush* pbrushOld = pDC->SelectObject(&m_brush);
   CRect rect;
   pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
   pDC->PatBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
   pDC->SelectObject(pbrushOld);
   return TRUE;
}
```